# How to perform an action if a certain word is inputted

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to make a password creator and manager, currently in the early stages and I am trying to make a program that randomly generates passwords and writes those random passwords to specific .txt files depending on the user input whether they want a pwd for Steam, discord, Gmail, etc.
For example, if the user inputs "get new pwd steam" I want it to write to the "steam.txt" file. I'm struggling to find out how to detect different words in the user input to write to those different files.
I currently have the code to a point where I can write to the steam .txt but only that one. How do I detect what the user input is and write to those specific files?

Here is my code:

```py
import secrets
import string
import os


newpw = input("")

if newpw == "get new pwd steam":
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    num = string.digits
    spec_char = string.punctuation

    alphabet = letters + num + spec_char
    pwd_length = 12

    while True:
        pwd = ''
        for i in range(pwd_length):
            pwd += ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet))

        if (any(char in spec_char for char in pwd) and
                sum(char in num for char in pwd) >= 2):
            break
        file = open("steam", "w")
        file.write(pwd)
        file.close()
        print(pwd)
```

Comment: You'd want to user to input the information bit by bit as in first you'll ask for action (`get new pwd`) and ask for which platform.

Comment: Thanks man, created new variable to ask questions bit by bit and got it working, only problem I have now is very big chunks of code, im sure there are ways to reduce it down but this is good for now just learning.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm struggling to find out how to detect different words in the user input to write to those different files

The first thing that comes to mind is the **re (regex)** module.

```py
newpw = input("Enter your request: ")

# match the last word with (\w+)
match = re.match(r"get new pwd (\w+)", newpw)
```

After that, check to see if there is a match. If so, get `match.group(1)` for the name of the file (steam, discord, etc..), save that to a variable (in this case platform), and write that to a file using the `with` syntax:

```py
with open(f"{platform}.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(password)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll be honest im a bit of a noob for all that dont quite understand it yet but ill keep looking into it thanks.

Comment: Regex is useful but an overkill for such a simple task. (Also, fan of Hunt of Odin too. :^))

Comment: @doneforaiur yeah split would work or just asking for it like you said. my b

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a particular substring or set of characters is in the user input, then use

```
app = input("Enter app":
pwd = input("Enter password:")

if 'gmail' in app:
   # do something

   # write pwd in gmail.txt
```

This is how you can split the input in characters.

```
pwd = input("Enter password:")
pwd_chars = pwd.split()
```

Comment: Why use `for loop` instead of just `split()`?

Comment: Thanks Diego. Correct. I changed my answer.